# Colour-coded 3D Plot in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am new to R, so can someone please help with this?

I have a data frame with 4 columns: x,y,z and freq. One row in this frame represents one point in 3D space (x,y,z are x-,y- and z- coordinates respectively) and it's frequency. I want to plot these points and make these points coloured such that the color is decided by the frequency. For eg: All points with frequency 0 are blue, between 1 and 5 are red, between 5 and 10 are orange, between 10 and 15 are yellow and so on. Some points can have a frequency of 0 also. But I don't know the range of frequency. Max no of colors to be used is 10. Also, there should be a scale explaining the meaning of colors.

I have been trying to correct the following code and make it work, but it`s just not working:

```
lev <- levels(factor(t$freq)); 
n <- as.numeric(lev); 
n <- n+1; 
plot3d(t$x,t$z,t$z,col=n);
```

Please help! Thank you.

PS- Please tell the solution using rgl package
PPS - I have been trying to manipulate the col arguement in plot3d function of rgl package, but I am unable to get the desired result.

Comment: Please add an example of your problem (data + code), and what you have tried so far. This makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I have been trying to correct the following code and make it work, but it`s just not working:
lev <- levels(factor(t$freq));
n <- as.numeric(lev);
n <- n+1;
plot3d(t$x,t$z,t$z,col=n);

Comment: I would add these kinds of details to your original post, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow. I haven`t posted a lot of questions before, so I didn`t know. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Do note that we do not have your data (`t`), which makes it harder to answer the question.

Comment: You can take any set of random values for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would load package *rgl* and do

```
plot3d(x,y,z, col=colors)
```

That means that you should prepare a list of color values that is of the same length as x,y,z lists so that you have a color selected for each x,y,z point.

the other part would be to make the list. I would try

```
givecolor = function(freq){
 if(freq < 1) "red"
 else if ....
}

colors = sapply(mydataframe[,"freq"], givecolor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build a vector of colors that is the same length as the number of points you are plotting. You then pass this vector as the `col` argument to the rgl `plot3d()` function. See this page for a demonstration that uses the `iris` dataset: http://planspace.org/2013/02/03/pca-3d-visualization-and-clustering-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

First you should select a palette you like and pick the number of colors you want, e.g. palette=rainbow(10). Then use a factor you get from splitting your data 10 ways to set your color from the palette.

See [3d scatterplot in R using rgl plot3d - different size for each data point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341963/3d-scatterplot-in-r-using-rgl-plot3d-different-size-for-each-data-point) for how to effectively split a dataframe by a newly created factor. That question is w.r.t. size, but it also works for color.